# How to parse file as an argument using cat command

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, cat

I need to parse the file as an argument to my C code by using `cat`:

```
cat filename | ./code -n 10
```

So that it works the same way as:

```
./code filename -n 10
```

Or is there any way to read the file directly through the `cat` command by using `read` syscall? I was thinking about something like this:

```
read([file from the cat], buf, sizeof(buf));
```

and maybe if I do it this way I don't need to do it like this:

```
fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY);
read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

It s the first time I see `cat` used this way; I tried to google it but couldn't find anything.
I am a beginner in C language and Unix; any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Unclear which of the two you actually want: the *read from stdin* version or the *read from a named file* version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first answer on stackoverflow, so bear with me...

"Running cat filename reads the contents of the specified file and writes them to standard output. | between two commands means connect standard output of the left command to **standard input of the right command**." [cat and pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466463/cat-and-pipe-vs-redirection)

When you propose to read from "file from the cat"...
`read([file from the cat], buf, sizeof(buf));`

...you're meant to specify a file descriptor for the read command [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

It turns out, you can pass in the file descriptor of "0" to read from standard input.

So you would simply do the following:

`read(0, buf, sizeof(buf));`

Comment: Yes!! That worked, thank you. I actually tried this before but it didn't work for me, I guess I just didn't compile my file lol. Anyways, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem...have a good day :)